# Customer authenticate

Tags: node.js, moltin

When I send post request to `https://api.molt.in/v1/customers/authenticate` I get strange return:

```
{"status":false,"error":"HTTP method used is not supported for this endpoint"}
```

I only get this error if I add custom header:

```
'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token_data.access_token
```

You can see my full code here:

```
var formData = {grant_type:'implicit', client_id: clientId}

    request.post({url:'https://api.molt.in/oauth/access_token',form:formData}, function (err, httpResponse, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        token_data = JSON.parse(body);
    });

    moltin.Authenticate(function(){

        var options = {url:'https://api.molt.in/v1/customers/authenticate',
            form:{email:"xxxx@xxx.com", password:'xxxx'},
            headers: {
                'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token_data.access_token
            }
            };

        function callBack(err, httpResponse, body){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("\naccess_token: "+token_data.access_token+"\nbody: "+body);
            res.send(body);
        }

        request.post(options,callBack);

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `https://api.molt.in/v1/customers/token` instead of `https://api.molt.in/v1/customers/authenticate` then you should get back the customer token that you can then use for subsequent requests.

If you're using JS and can add in the moltin SDK manually, build a copy from this branch: https://github.com/moltin/js-sdk/tree/feature/customer-logins

That should have support for using a `moltin.Customer.login()` method natively...

Comment: The code in the branch is missing the definition of the endpoint for Customer. After adding the line:  

    Customer.prototype.endpoint = 'customers';

it works perfectly.